# How to make object scale at specific point on Z axis based on bone?

Tags: rigging, bones

So, I'm working on a rig and I hope to get a mouth rig working.  Behind the mouth is a plane which I've textured red to act as the inside of the character's mouth.  Problem is, that while it might be possible to move the red plane witha bone, I haven't figured out how to scale it.  The jaw will deform and as a result, some of the red texturing will not be able to deform with the jaw and make it appear seamless.

Comment: can you add a screen shot of the model with the bones.

Comment: I can't.  I haven't rigged the model quite yet  this issue stems from problems in the past with a similar issue.  I do however, have the mesh modelled.  If you're looking for a basic rundown of the problem, it's that I have a flat plane which acts as the color of the mouth interior.  I'm trying to get it to deform with the lower jaw bone I'm going to place.

Comment: OK, so you just want a general how to deform a plane with multiple bones answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling the bone should scale the mesh as well. It is really easy to try it out:

1. Add a plane
2. Add an armature
3. Parent the plane to the armature (automatic weights)
4. Scale the bone

Move the mesh origin point in order to change the scaling origin.

Comment: If I scale the bone, then that scales the lower jaw as well.  What I'm trying to do is translate the lower jaw and in the process, warp the lower half of the plane so it matches with the position of the jaw.

Comment: Well, then add a separate bone for your plane, which is not linked to the lower jaw via weight painting. Possibly some drivers and corrective shape keys would help as well.

Comment: If you use corrective shape keys, then you don't need the extra bone, and the rig is easier to use, because only one bone needs to be animated. However, the setup is a bit more complicated.